# gfortran associates wrong type-bound procedure

Tags: fortran, procedure, gfortran, derived-types

When we compile (gfortran 5.3 or 7.2) and run the following code, line 9 of the main.f03 ends up in a subroutine that is never called. Can anyone explain why?

main.f03:

```
program main
    use minimalisticcase
    implicit none

    type(DataStructure) :: data_structure
    type(DataLogger) :: data_logger

    call data_structure%init()
    call data_logger%init(data_structure)
end program
```

minimalisticcase.f03:

```
module minimalisticcase
    implicit none

    type, public :: DataStructure
        integer :: i
    contains
        procedure, pass :: init => init_data_structure
        procedure, pass :: a => beginning_of_alphabet
    end type



    type, public :: DataLogger
        type(DataStructure), pointer :: data_structure
        contains
                procedure, pass :: init => init_data_logger
                procedure, pass :: do_something => do_something
    end type

contains
    subroutine init_data_structure(self)
        implicit none
        class(DataStructure), intent(inout) :: self
        write(*,*) 'init_data_structure'
    end subroutine

    subroutine beginning_of_alphabet(self)
        implicit none
        class(DataStructure), intent(inout) :: self

        write(*,*) 'beginning_of_alphabet'
    end subroutine

    subroutine init_data_logger(self, data_structure)
        implicit none
        class(DataLogger), intent(inout) :: self
        class(DataStructure), target :: data_structure
        write(*,*) 'init_data_logger'

        self%data_structure => data_structure
        call self%do_something()
    end subroutine

    subroutine do_something(self)
        implicit none
        class(DataLogger), intent(inout) :: self

        write(*,*) 'do_something'
    end subroutine
end module
```

On line 40 of 'minimalisticcase.f03' we call 'do_something' of the DataLogger. But instead the 'beginning_of_alphabet' subroutin of DataStructure is executed!

Apparently one can fix this by changing line 13 in 'minimalisticcase.f03' from `type(DataStructure), pointer :: data_structure` to `class(DataStructure), pointer :: data_structure`.

But why?

Comment: Everything is working as expected for me with both ifort 17 and gfortran 7.2. First `init_data_structure`, then `init_data_logger`, and finally `do_something`.

Comment: @ Matt: That's interessting! I can reproduce the behaviour both on my windows and my linux machine. On which platform are you working?

Comment: I tested this on Windows 10 (64bit), with gfortran in WSL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in gfortran. I posted it on Bugzilla as https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82312. The error is now fixed on the GCC trunk.

A temporary workaround is to encase the pointer assignment in a select type, thusly:

```
    select type (data_structure)
      type is (DataStructure)
        self%data_structure => data_structure
    end select
```

Comment: The report https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82312 Welcome Paul. BTW, we normally don't sign and use greetings here, as your name is put under your post automatically next to the icon on the right side.

Comment: Your workaround is different from the one I mentioned in the question. Is there a reasion to prefer one over the other? (and thank you to file the report)

Comment: The bug is now fixed on 7-branch and is closed. Thanks for the report.